# mysql request don't show every post

Tags: mysql, wordpress, events

I have do a request for take all posts on my wordpress bdd, where post_type = 'tribe_events", post_status='publish', and with some left join for another data (like start date, end date, etc...) but my request show only 155 lines, or if i do a simple request like

```
  SELECT * FROM `wp_4_posts` WHERE post_type = "tribe_events" AND post_status = 'publish'
```

i have 189 lines, so 34 lines are not here.

this is my request :

```
 SELECT pm1.meta_value _EventVenueID
 , p1.post_title event_type
 , p2.post_title organiser
 , p3.post_title venues
 , pm2.meta_value _EventStartDate
 , pm3.meta_value _EventEndDate
 , pm4.meta_value _EventOrganizerID
 , p10.guid
 , p20.ID
 , wp_4_terms.name


 FROM wp_4_posts p1 
 JOIN wp_4_postmeta pm1 
   ON p1.ID = pm1.post_id 
  AND pm1.meta_key = '_EventVenueID'

 LEFT
 JOIN wp_4_posts p3
   ON p3.id = pm1.meta_value

 LEFT 
 JOIN wp_4_postmeta pm2 
   ON p1.ID = pm2.post_id 
  AND pm2.meta_key = '_EventStartDate'

 LEFT 
 JOIN wp_4_postmeta pm3 
   ON p1.ID = pm3.post_id 
  AND pm3.meta_key = '_EventEndDate'

 LEFT 
 JOIN wp_4_postmeta pm4 
   ON p1.ID = pm4.post_id 
  AND pm4.meta_key = '_EventOrganizerID'

 LEFT
 JOIN wp_4_posts p2
   ON p2.id = pm4.meta_value 

 LEFT
 JOIN wp_4_posts p10
   ON p10.id = p1.id

 LEFT
 JOIN wp_4_posts p20
   ON p20.id = p1.id



  LEFT JOIN wp_4_term_relationships 
  ON p1.ID = wp_4_term_relationships.object_id 

  LEFT 
  JOIN wp_4_term_taxonomy 
  ON
wp_4_term_taxonomy.term_taxonomy_id=wp_4_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id 
 LEFT JOIN wp_4_terms ON  wp_4_terms.term_id = wp_4_term_taxonomy.term_id 




WHERE p1.post_type = 'tribe_events' 
AND p1.post_status = 'publish'
```

I don't understand why i have only 155 lines, do you have an idea ?

Thanks a lot for your help !

Comment: Your first join is an inner join.

Comment: Hi Magenta and thanks for your answers, it work perfectly !